# How to insert multiple data in the database

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, row

I'm trying to save all the rows using laravel, This is my dynamic table code:

```
    $(function(){
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){ //Introduce los nuevos campo
    var form_data = {};
    form_data["sexo"] = $('.payment-form #sexo option:selected').text();
    form_data["color"] = $('.payment-form input[name="color"]').val();
    form_data["raza"] = $('.payment-form #raza option:selected').text();
    form_data["tipo"] = $('.payment-form #tipo option:selected').text();
    form_data["precio"] = $('.payment-form input[name="precio"]').val();
    form_data["peso"] = $('.payment-form input[name="peso"]').val();
    form_data["monto"] = parseFloat($('.payment-form input[name="precio"]').val()*$('.payment-form input[name="peso"]').val()).toFixed(2);
    form_data["remove-row"] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $.each(form_data, function( type, value ) {
        $('<td class="input-'+type+'"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
    });
    $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row); 
    calc_total();
}); });
```

This is my table in html

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
        <h4>Estado:</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table preview-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sexo</th>
                                <th>Color</th>
                                <th>Raza</th>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                <th>Precio x kg</th>
                                <th>Peso</th>
                                <th>Monto</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody> <!-- preview content goes here-->
                    </table>
                </div>                            
            </div>
        </div>
```

How  should I set my controller/view to insert every row in the database?

**Update:** Here is a pic of my problem:

[image: Link to image]

Answer (score 0):

Well Laravel won't really care if you're data is in an html table or not. Have a look at this since you seem kinda lost: http://culttt.com/2013/05/13/setting-up-your-first-laravel-4-model/

TL;DR

Naturally you're going to need a model that represents the table you want to save your data in.

Then you want to figure how to submit you view data to PHP either as a form or as an ajax post request.

```
<form method="POST" action="some-route-you-want" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="field1" type="text">          
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="field2" type="text">
    ...
    <input class="btn" id="btn_login" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You should have a PUT route properly set up as well:

```
Route::put('some-route-you-want', array('uses' => 'SomeController@save'));
```

And in the controller (or repository, wherever you want it), you perform the code that persists the data into the database. Though ideally you'd want to validate the form here and perform whatever sanitation you need.

```
/**
 * Inserts data into the database
 *
 */
public function save()
{
    $someEntity = new SomeTable;
    $someEntity->someField1 = Input::get('field1');
    $someEntity->someField2 = Input::get('field2');
    ...
    $someEntity->save(); 
}
```